# Copying a boost.python object

Tags: python, boost-python

I have some boost python classes, which I instantiate in python.  I want to copy them.  So, if I have

```
p = Bernoulli(0.5)
```

I want to do

```
q = Bernoulli(p)
```

But what if I don't know p's type?  I tried to do this:

```
q = copy.deepcopy(p)
```

but python said it couldn't pickle p.

Is my only solution to add a clone() function to the interface of Bernoulli?  Or can I have that method automatically generated somehow?  Can copy.deepcopy be made to work with Boost.python objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From http://mail.python.org/pipermail/cplusplus-sig/2009-May/014505.html

```
#define PYTHON_ERROR(TYPE, REASON) \
{ \
    PyErr_SetString(TYPE, REASON); \
    throw bp::error_already_set(); \
}

template<class T>
inline PyObject * managingPyObject(T *p)
{
    return typename bp::manage_new_object::apply<T *>::type()(p);
}

template<class Copyable>
bp::object
generic__copy__(bp::object copyable)
{
    Copyable *newCopyable(new Copyable(bp::extract<const Copyable
&>(copyable)));
    bp::object
result(bp::detail::new_reference(managingPyObject(newCopyable)));

    bp::extract<bp::dict>(result.attr("__dict__"))().update(
        copyable.attr("__dict__"));

    return result;
}

template<class Copyable>
bp::object
generic__deepcopy__(bp::object copyable, bp::dict memo)
{
    bp::object copyMod = bp::import("copy");
    bp::object deepcopy = copyMod.attr("deepcopy");

    Copyable *newCopyable(new Copyable(bp::extract<const Copyable
&>(copyable)));
    bp::object
result(bp::detail::new_reference(managingPyObject(newCopyable)));

    // HACK: copyableId shall be the same as the result of id(copyable)
in Python -
    // please tell me that there is a better way! (and which ;-p)
    int copyableId = (int)(copyable.ptr());
    memo[copyableId] = result;

    bp::extract<bp::dict>(result.attr("__dict__"))().update(
        deepcopy(bp::extract<bp::dict>(copyable.attr("__dict__"))(),
memo));

    return result;
}
```

To use it:

```
class_<foo>(foo)
   .def("__copy__", &generic__copy__< foo >)
   .def("__deepcopy__", &generic__deepcopy__< foo >)
   .def(init< const foo & >())
```

Comment: I would have posted that myself you know. Now I can only up vote yours. GRRRRR!

Comment: @Matthew, Ha ha ha.  Perhaps you would be so kind as to explain to me what I should do on a 64-bit compiler since the pointer is not castable to int?

Comment: @Matthew, also, I'm not sure exactly why this generic__copy__ is better than Philipp's?  Is it because it copies anything that you might have added to the object's dict?

Comment: (I ended up casting to int via long long, since I noticed that the python ids seem to be 32-bit ints.)

Comment: @Neil G, I am not sure what you ought to do with a 64-bit situation. Right now, our wrapped library only exists in 32-bit, so we don't have that problem. the real solution is for the C/Python API or BP to expose a portable way to get id(copyable) as an int.

Comment: @Neil G, Yes proper \_\_dict\_\_ handling is one way in which my generic__copy__ is better. I don't see any others off-hand.

Answer (score 2):

For copying, you can either implement the `__copy__` and `__deepcopy__` special methods (one of them could just wrap the copy constructor, depending on the C++ copy semantics of the class), or add [pickling support](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/python/doc/v2/pickle.html). The `copy` module will use the special copying methods if they are available and the pickling methods otherwise.

Here is an example for using the copy constructor to implement `__copy__`:

```
template<typename T> const T copyObject(const T& v) { return v; }
boost::python::class_<C>("C").def("__copy__", copyObject<C>);
```

Comment: how do I implement `__copy__` in terms of the copy constructor using boost.python?

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I am getting the error: `Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    Dirichlet.__deepcopy__(Dirichlet, dict)
did not match C++ signature:
    __deepcopy__(Dirichlet)`

Comment: @Neil: The `__deepcopy__` method has a different signature: it is passed a dictionary for memoization.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can make boost::python objects deep-copyable (and also pickable) by implementing the  `__setstate__` and  `__getstate__` methods on your object.

Basically, `__getstate__` should return an (python) object that represents the internal state of your object, while `__setstate__` obviously accepts said object and updates the state of your object.

If your object takes arguments for `__init__`, you should also look at implementing `__getinitargs__`.

See the Python [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#the-pickle-protocol) for more information.

Comment: Making a BP object picklable is by far the WORST way to make it copyable. C++ has nice efficient copy ctors. Pickling involves a round trip through a string, and is hideously over-expensive in comparison. And this is not even the best way to make a BP object picklable. See: boost::python::pickle_suite