# Make Python class inherited from boost-python class copyable

Tags: python, boost-python, deep-copy

I have a class that inherits from a boost-python class:

```
class Magnet(CMagnet):   # CMagnet is a C++ based boost-python class
    def __init__(self):
        CMagnet.__init__(self)

    def python_method(self):
        ...
```

In the C++ implementation of CMagnet I used the code from [1](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/cplusplus-sig/2009-May/014505.html), as posted in [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696966/copying-a-boost-python-object).

I now have the following problem: When I do the following:

```
magnet = Magnet()
magnet_2 = copy.deepcopy(magnet)
```

then `magnet` is of type `Magnet`, `magnet_2`, however, is of type `CMagnet`. I need it to be also of type `Magnet`. It lacks all `Magnet` methods. How do I get deepcopy to copy (and return) the entire `Magnet` object and not only a copy of the `CMagnet` part?

Comment: There's a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4696966/648661) which indicates that you should implement the `__deepcopy__` yourself, but I don't know if you're already doing it, or if your implementation have any bug; like @Leon said, it's better if you provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 4):

Since you didn't provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) I cannot quickly check if the following dirty trick works, but I think that it should.

You can add a `__deepcopy__()` method to your class that delegates the work to the underlying `boost-python` object and then fixes the type of the result.

```
def __deepcopy__(self, memo):
    result = super().__deepcopy__(memo)
    result.__class__ = self.__class__
    return result
```

> How do I get deepcopy to copy (and return) the entire Magnet object and not only a copy of the CMagnet part?

Note that the `generic__deepcopy__()` function copies all fields of the input object, therefore it is only the type that is wrong - the content of the copy object should be correct.

Comment: Perfect, it works. You are right, it was only the type that was wrong, the methods have been there all the time. The second line in the example you provide should read 

result = super().__deepcopy__(memo)

Providing all the material to recreate the problem, even a minimal set, is not easy with boost python, as it requires quite some of infrastructure to set the whole thing up. But luckily the information provided was sufficient after all.

Comment: @zeus300 Fixed the second line. Thanks.